# convert mathematica formula into gnuplot syntax

Tags: syntax, wolfram-mathematica, gnuplot

So far I did all my plotting with Gnuplot. Recently I started using Mathematica and sometimes I would like to do the plotting still with gnuplot especially when it comes down to some "theory and data" plots. So my question is, is there a possibility to convert the Mathematica formulas into gnuplot syntax like formulas?

A bit more detailed information about what I would like to achieve.

Given a Formula in Mathematica eg.:

```
Exp[x^2+2 x] (1 + 2 x^3) (x+1)^2
```

should be translated into the following syntax:

```
exp(x**2 + 2*x)*(1+2*x**3)*(x+1)**2
```

I tried to work with the replace function, and to come up with replacement rules, like:

```
{x^a_ -> x ** a, (x + a_)^b_ -> (x + a) ** b}
```

The Exp[x] should go to exp(x), and a x -> a*x, what I did not achiev yet. Addiotionlly this works only for very simple expressions. If the formulas get more and more nested this clearly does not work, because these rules do not take all combinations into account.

So I am interested in a generic way to do that with a function, as mentioned in the comment. I would be glad, if somebody could show me how this would be done, since I am bloody Mathematica beginner.Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you can try using FortranForm, it will convert the powers but the functions will be different. In addition, there is a very active Stack Exchange site for Mathematica, you can try there: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: right , something line this: `FortranForm[ expression  /. { Exp[a_] :> exp[a] } ]` will get you a long way.

Comment: agentp your suggestion does the charm, thx. There is only one small detail, namely that every new line start with a hyphen (-), which one has to remove manually. Would be nice to remove that hyphen automatically too.

Comment: you can suppress linewrap all together with `PageWidth->Infinity` ( see the `FortranForm` page. )

Comment: @agentp Could you please provide that as answer?